# Xamarin iOS set plist values

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, plist

I have my own plist for some setting values, added under resources folder. I can read these value but could not reset them through code.

For resetting i have

```
 NSMutableDictionary dictionary = NSMutableDictionary.FromFile (fileName);
 NSObject value = NSObject.FromObject(newurl);
 NSString key = new NSString("Webpage URL");
 dictionary.SetValueForKey (value, key);
```

The code does not change the value for the kay.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see any place where you write your dictionary back into a file. I think that if you will do this it fix your problem.
Second, why not to store your application settings in NSUserDefaults , I think it's a little bit more clean:

```
var value = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("page-url")

NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(value, "page-url");
```